# Simplifying $s=r+\frac{r}{0.3}-r\cos\theta+\sqrt{\left(\frac{r}{0.3}\right)^2-(r\sin\theta)^2}$ to solve for $r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Basically I have boiled an equation down to the following:

$$
s = r + \frac{r}{0.3} - r\cdot\cos\theta + \sqrt{\left(\frac{r}{0.3}\right)^2 - (r\cdot\sin\theta)^2}
$$

I am trying to rearrange/reduce to solve for $r$. The variables $s$ and $a$ are known.

I get this far:

$$
s = r\left(1 + \frac{1}{0.3} - \cos\theta + \cdots(?) \right)
$$

I get stuck getting the last square root bit simplified to remove/reduce down to a single $r$ outside the bracket.

Please tell me the right terminology for what I am trying to do and also just how to get that last term sorted.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Replace r inside the radical sign, if r is positive, this  is your last term, other wise add a minus sign before it.

Comment: Please use \cdot to get a multiplication dot that is centered instead of a period or juxtaposition.  r \cdot 0.3 gives $r \cdot 0.3$ and you can tell the two dots apart.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull a factor of $r$ out of the square root by dividing the terms under it by $r^2$. So assuming $r \gt 0$
$$s = r + \frac{r}{0.3} - r \cos\theta + \sqrt{\left(\frac{r}{0.3}\right)^2 - (r\sin\theta)^2}\\
=\left(r + \frac{r}{0.3} - r \cos\theta + r\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{0.3}\right)^2 - (\sin\theta)^2}\right)\\
=r\left(1 + \frac{1}{0.3} -  \cos\theta + \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{0.3}\right)^2 - (\sin\theta)^2}\right)$$
If $r$ might be less than $0$ the one that comes out of the square root s $|r|$ and will not combine so nicely.  Of course, you can clean up the constants.

Comment: Thank you Ross. You say divide the square root part by $r^2$ I am not totally clear how you did that. Also, is that $r$ times the square root or the "r root of..."?

Comment: Hmm just realised that your bottom line is what I originally thought of as but the result for "r" didn't seem right so I thought I had it wrong... Maybe not. I'll revisit. Thanks again